# Symfony2 loads wrong path

Tags: php, symfony

i ran into a problem with my Symfony2 installation. I have 2 symfony installations running alongside. `path/to/sym1` and `path/to/sym2`. Now something in the `sym2` is wrong, as it searches module files in the `path/to/sym1` directory. Weird.

It somehow affects the cache as well:

- When i clear the cache inside `sym2` using `php app/console cache:clear` the cache directory of `sym1` is also affected.
- When i manually clear the contents of `../sym2/app/cache/prod` the directory gets filled also.

So i tried obviously to clear the cache. It did not work. I also tried to rebuild the bootstrap.php.cache file, as the problem for me seemed to occur somewhere inside this. It did not work.

However when i renamed `sym1` i got a stacktrace giving some insights where the change of directory occurs.

```
12 at Controller->render('MyBundle:Admin:mailgroup.html.twig', array('mailgroups' => array([..]) in /path/to/sym1/src/MyBundle/Controller/AdminController.php line 75
13 at AdminController->mailgroupsAction('html')
14 at call_user_func_array(array(object(AdminController), 'mailgroupsAction'), array('html')) in /path/to/sym2/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2976
15 at HttpKernel->handleRaw(object(Request), '1') in /path/to/sym2/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2938
16 at HttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /path/to/sym2/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 3087
17 at ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(object(Request), '1', true) in /path/to/sym2/app/bootstrap.php.cache line 2337
18 at Kernel->handle(object(Request)) in /path/to/sym2/web/app_dev.php line 28
```

As you can see, obviously the wrong controller gets loaded inside `bootstrap.php.cache`. Where does this information come from? I searched all my configs as well as `AppKernel.php`, `web/app_dev.php` and `bootstrap.php.cache` without success.

Comment: What does you projects trees look like?

Comment: is the default one

Comment: I wanted to know if your two sf directories are in the same directory.

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes they are, actually the `/path/to/` from my question is the same for both. So there is `sym1` and `sym2` in the same folder.

Comment: And what your vhosts look like? Either it's because of vhosts or composer's cache I think

Comment: Hey actually i don't think vhost could be the reason, as the problems during cache clear arise from the command line. So no vhosts involded. My Vhosts look pretty unspectacular though `<VirtualHost *:80>` `ServerName` and `DocumentRoot` set.

Comment: @smarber it's been a while, but a little update: not using the same parent directory seems to resolve my issue. I really don't know why, since locally on my machine it does not seem to be a problem. Maybe there is really something wrong with Vhosts, but i really can't see anything there.